# How to export python files for other use?

Tags: python, file, export

I am looking to export some `.py` files so I can include them in a website. I am not sure any method to export the files however. Could someone please link some useful information or explain a procedure so the files can be executed using buttons on a website (particularly a HTML site)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you want to do. Do you want to execute the files on the internet or just host them for download?

Comment: Execute them on the internet e.g. a button on the website which will execute the python program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UWSGI as an intermediary between your Python files and nginx (as a web server). But this is not as easy as executing php files, since the php executor comes with any web server. Or call python files as external programs from your existing site.

Comment: Yes, calling them as external programs that can be run on the website is exactly what I want to do, but I am not sure how

Answer (score 0):

if your are looking to import function or classes in a file and use them in another file or project, then this might be what you are looking for [imports in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-file/)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I want. My intention is to execute the .py files ON a website (e.g. by pressing a button to execute). The .py files themselves are completed